# find the index i of a sorted array y[:], such that y[i-1] <= x <y[i]

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

```
getindex(x,y)
```

**Input:** a value `x`, and a sorted array `y[:]`  (no repeat element)

**Output:** the index  `i`, such that `y[i-1] <= x <y[i]`

The time complexity  should be **O(log(N))**

Is there a Python/Numpy function we can use?

**For example:**

```
y[0]=-0.2
y[1]=1.5
y[2]=1.9
y[3]=3.2
```

Then

`getindex(-4.0,y)` returns 0

`getindex(0.5,y)` returns 1

`getindex(6.0,y)` returns 4

Answer (score 1):

**numpy.searchsorted**

I find it here:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html